# How to exclude page from sitemap

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

We implement "noindex" on page(s) with page metadata field.
On webpage section "head" this is visible

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

It should be excluded from **sitemap.xml** because SEO search engines expect that.

Whats is the way to go?

Nothing OOTB?

We need an attribute in SitemapItem when website is producing the sitemap.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC start the names of the items (Pages and SGs) with an underscore `_`. Then do the required actions to regenerate the sitemap.

The DXA templating code is available on GitHub so feel free to look through the code, there might be other ways as well besides the underscore. Also, another good place to refer is the [documentation](https://docs.rws.com/publications/DXA/SDL%20DXA%202.2)

Comment: Thanks for answer. That works and for now usable. Other option where model maybe "SitemapItem" expands is not clear from the doc.